# Biblatex - changing dash style breaks capital letter of pages

Tags: biblatex

Here is a **good** MWE with no issues - simply print a bibliography item

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@book{knuth1998art,
    title={The art of computer programming},
    author={Knuth, Donald Ervin},
    pages={1-200}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Well bibliography]

I need to make shorter dashes, so I renewed next commands: `\bibrangedash` and `\newblockpunct`, so here is MWE with **issue** - small letter after new dash

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@book{knuth1998art,
    title={The art of computer programming},
    author={Knuth, Donald Ervin},
    pages={1-200}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{
    \renewcommand*{\bibrangedash}{-}
    \renewcommand*{\newblockpunct}{-- }
}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Issues bibliography]

I'm not so good with latex internals to find out by myself how to fix it :(

Comment: The culprit is `\newblockpunct.`

Comment: Yes, I know, comment/uncomment of redefinition clarifies this. But I need to renew this command to make dash as wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long search in docs, I found out the solution (section 4.7.6 of biblatex documentation) - just need to add `\bibsentence` as follows:

**NOTE**: It is important to place `%` at the ond of the line to avoid empty lines in bibliography

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{
    \renewcommand*{\bibrangedash}{\hyphen}%
    \renewcommand*{\newblockpunct}{\addperiod\addnbspace\textendash\space\bibsentence}%
}
```

Comment: You will find that the default in `gost-standard.bbx` is `\renewcommand*{\newblockpunct}{\addperiod\addnbspace\textemdash\space\bibsentence}`, so you might want to use  `\renewcommand*{\newblockpunct}{\addperiod\addnbspace\textendash\space\bibsentence}`. AFAIK, `\newblockpunct` is not language-specific, so it doesn't have to sit in `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}`, but it doesn't really hurt if it does in your MWE.

Comment: Thank you moewe, your comment helped me to find original definiton and resolve another annoying bug with empty lines in bibliography -- because of missing `%` signs at the end